# Get all rows from table where linked table has value

Tags: sql

I'm trying to get a list from two tables in MySQL. By looking at artist_albums_link -> artist_uid and matching to artists_albums. The list should contain the same albums but as well all albums with the artist that user doesn't have.

Wanted result for user_uid = '5'

```
album_uid       artist_uid                      title       user_uid
album:another   artist:00N1TiCLsiP8IE24hw0rl9   yahoo       5
album:test      artist:00N1TiCLsiP8IE24hw0rl9   Test        5
album:notinlist artist:00N1TiCLsiP8IE24hw0rl9   add this    null
```

This is the data tables below.
Notice how user '5'  has two album_links but because the artist has one more album it's also shown. The album "not show" isn't in the users albums_link so it will not be in the list.

table: artists_albums

```
album_uid       artist_uid                      title
album:another   artist:00N1TiCLsiP8IE24hw0rl9   yahoo   
album:noshow    artist:00sazWvoTLOqg5MFwC68Um   not show    
album:notinlist artist:00N1TiCLsiP8IE24hw0rl9⇥  add this    
album:test      artist:00N1TiCLsiP8IE24hw0rl9   Test
```

table: artist_albums_link

```
uid user_uid    artist_uid                      album_uid   
1   5           artist:00N1TiCLsiP8IE24hw0rl9   album:test  
2   6           artist:00N1TiCLsiP8IE24hw0rl9   album:test  
3   5           artist:00N1TiCLsiP8IE24hw0rl9   album:another
```

Trying to use join to get the null value with no success. The new value a.updated (timestamp) is correct for the row, but value b.found (timestamp) for album "album:notinlist" is wrong, this post doesn't exist in artist_albums_link.

```
SELECT  a.album_uid, a.artist_uid, a.title, a.updated, b.user_uid,  b.found
FROM  artist_albums a LEFT OUTER JOIN artist_albums_link b ON a.artist_uid = b.artist_uid
WHERE b.user_uid = '5'
```

result:

```
album_uid       artist_uid                      title       updated                 user_uid    found
album:another   artist:00N1TiCLsiP8IE24hw0rl9   yahoo       2013-03-20 11:29:08     5           2013-03-18 11:24:47
album:another   artist:00N1TiCLsiP8IE24hw0rl9   yahoo       2013-03-20 11:29:08     5           2013-03-19 11:29:59
album:notinlist artist:00N1TiCLsiP8IE24hw0rl9   add this    2013-03-15 11:41:20     5           2013-03-18 11:24:47
album:notinlist artist:00N1TiCLsiP8IE24hw0rl9   add this    2013-03-15 11:41:20     5           2013-03-19 11:29:59
album:test      artist:00N1TiCLsiP8IE24hw0rl9   Test        2013-03-20 11:23:41     5           2013-03-18 11:24:47
album:test      artist:00N1TiCLsiP8IE24hw0rl9   Test        2013-03-20 11:23:41     5           2013-03-19 11:29:59
```

Comment: Same as code below. The problem is that the album 'add this' is showing with user_uid, I wan't it to be null or "" so I can see if user is missing album.

Comment: When adding another column with timestamp I can see that all results has same date. Looks like user_uid, found taking first row value and applying to the rest :/

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following code:

```
SELECT a.album_uid, a.artist_uid, a.title, b.user_uid
FROM  artists_albums a, artist_albums_link b
WHERE a.artist_uid = b.artist_uid  AND b.user_uid = 5;
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: This gives a list (double posts) so adding GROUP BY and then we are almost there.

SELECT a.album_uid, a.artist_uid, a.title, b.user_uid
FROM  artist_albums a, artist_albums_link b
WHERE a.artist_uid = b.artist_uid  AND b.user_uid = '5' GROUP BY a.album_uid;

this list gives the album 'add this' with a user_uid, I would like this to be '' or null to be able to see that the user doesn't have this album.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found something that works.

```
SELECT a.album_uid, a.artist_uid, a.title, a.updated, b.user_uid, b.found
FROM artist_albums AS a
LEFT OUTER JOIN artist_albums_link AS b ON a.album_uid = b.album_uid
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT artist_uid FROM artist_albums_link WHERE artist_uid = a.artist_uid ) AND (b.user_uid = '5' OR b.user_uid is null)
```